# Cómo hacer que no puedan ingresar una fecha final menor a una fecha de inicio?

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo una tabla así:

```
db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string', unique=True),
                Field('remitente', 'string'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'date'),
                Field('fecha_salida', 'date'),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )
```

y uso un controlador SQLFORM.grid para la gestion de los datos (Agregar,Editar, Eliminar)

```
def registro():
    form = SQLFORM.grid(db.registro)
    return dict(form=form)
```

y mi vista esta definida asi:

```
{{ extend 'layout.html' }}

    {{ block page_name }}Registro{{ end }}

{{ block content }}
    {{ =form }}
{{ end }}
```

si pongo esto `default=now` en el campo `fecha_ingreso` hará que por defecto de llene la fecha actual pero cual es la manera correcta para hacer que en la misma tabla al ingresar la fecha de salida esta no me permita registrar una fecha menor a ella, lo he intentado a nivel de `web2py` pero no tengo resultados.

Answer (score 3):

Para la solución que buscas, en el caso de web2py, a nivel de DAL (Database Abstraction Layer) como explica [la documentación](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#IS_DATE_IN_RANGE), podrías usar [IS_DATE_IN_RANGE](http://www.web2py.com.ar/examples/static/epydoc/web2py.gluon.validators.IS_DATE_IN_RANGE-class.html):

```
db.table.fecha_salida.requires = IS_DATE_IN_RANGE(format=T('%Y-%m-%d'),
        minimum=form.vars.fecha_ingreso if form.vars.fecha_ingreso else None,
        maximum=None,
        error_message='Debe ser mayor a %s' form.vars.fecha_ingreso.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if form.vars.fecha_ingreso else 'Fecha de ingreso es obligatoria'
```

Para realizar esta evaluación la podrías hacer a nivel de código de una manera más sencilla parecida a esta:

```
if fecha_salida > fecha_ingreso:
    db.registro.insert(remitente=remitente, fecha_salida=fecha_salida,fecha_ingreso=fecha_ingreso, ...)
```

O a nivel de base de datos con un Trigger, por ejemplo, en PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validar_fechas()
RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF new.fecha_salida > new.fecha_ingreso THEN
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE 
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'fecha de salida incorrecta';
END IF;
$BODY$

CREATE TRIGGER t_validar_fechas
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON registro
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE validar_fechas();
```

Comment: Esta bien tu respuesta, pero IS_DATE_IN_RANGE no me permite instanciar datos por lo que no seria posible hacer IS_DATE_IN_RANGE(minimum=db.registro.fecha_ingreso)

Comment: Tienes razón, de la manera que lo había puesto se realiza una validación estática. He actualizado la respuesta de la forma que se podría validar de forma dinámica cuando recoges las variables del formulario, aunque no he podido verificarlo. Espero que funcione :)

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: justo eso es lo que estoy tratando, voy a actualizar mi pregunta porque según leí tiene que ser con jquery o ajax